# The $\pm$ symbol in the square root of fractions, as well as in the quadratic formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I had $ \sqrt {a^2}= \frac{1+b}{4c^2}$ and wanted to solve for $a$, an easy thing to do would be to take the square root of both sides, giving $a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+b}{4c^2}}$

And then I would proceed to simplify the fraction by taking the square root of the numerator and denominator on the RHS. My question is: do we need to put the plus-minus symbol ($\pm)$ on *both* numerator and denominator? This would give  $a=\frac{\pm\sqrt{1+b}}{\pm\sqrt{4c^2}}$

This leads me to my second question: will the $\pm$ disappear after I square root the denominator, giving $a=\frac{\pm\sqrt{1+b}}{2c}$? Or must it be retained, giving us $a=\frac{\pm\sqrt{1+b}}{\pm2c}$ ?

I would really appreciate a clear and thorough explanation, because I'm trying to understand why the quadratic formula, $x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$ has the $\pm$ symbol for $\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}$, but not for the $2a$ in the denominator. I understand that the quadratic formula can be derived when completing the square is applied to the quadratic equation $ax^2 +bx +c=0$, but I am confused at the assigning of the $\pm$ symbol upon square rooting the RHS when we arrive at $(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$ in its derivation. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you know that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. So if $x^2=4$, then $\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{4} \implies |x|=|2| \implies |x|=2 \implies x= \pm 2$. Also if you think about it $\frac{-1}{2}=\frac{1}{-2}$, so $\frac{\pm a}{ \pm b}=\pm \frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you see “$\pm p$”, you can replace it with the statement “$p$ or $-p$” (you might have to tidy up the resulting statement for syntactic clarity). Essentially, you’re splitting your expression into **two cases**.

Note that while you technically can put $\pm$ on both the top and the bottom, the $2^2$ = **four cases** will reduce down to two cases.

You can obviously also put the $\pm$ only on the bottom (and not on the top). This will result in ugly expressions, though.

I mean, do you really enjoy looking at the following?

$$(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2 = \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$$

$$x+\frac{b}{2a} = \frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{\pm 2a}$$

$$x = \frac{b}{-2a} + \frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{\pm 2a}$$

These are all technically correct, though.